# Having trouble with Django forms "OperationalError: no such table" error

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to set up a form on Django that displays inputs on the page, but I get this error.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: firstapp_post
```

This doesn't happen right away, but when I try to use the submit feature on my form.

Right now this is what I have as my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

These are currently my forms:

```
from django import forms
from firstapp.models import Post

class IndexForm(forms.ModelForm):
    post = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('post',)
```

This is my views file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from firstapp.forms import IndexForm
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = IndexForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = IndexForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            text = form.cleaned_data['post']
            form = IndexForm()
            return redirect('home:home')

        args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

This is my base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Assignment 4</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "css/base.css" %}'/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>{{ variable }}</p>

        {% block body %}{% endblock %}

        <script src= '{% static "js/base.js" %}'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my home.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">
    <p>Home</p>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <p>{{ text }}</p>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Does anyone have any idea what this error even means or why I'm getting it? This has been driving me nuts. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message mentions, that particular table does not exist in your database.

You can run the following command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname
```

By running makemigrations, you’re telling Django that you’ve made some changes to your models and that you’d like the changes to be stored as a migration.

Now run migrate again to create those model tables in your database

```
python manage.py migrate
```

[Further Reading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models)